# C# "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"

Tags: c#

I am building a firewall controller using c#.
I am getting a :

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))

When I am trying to add firewall rules from a list. It seems to work out fine when I just create a rule and add it to the firewall directly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<INetFwRule2> RuleList = new List<INetFwRule2>();

    private Type netFwPolicy2Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
    private INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(netFwPolicy2Type);

        // Adding all fireWall rules in a List
        foreach (INetFwRule2 rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
        {
            RuleList.Add(rule);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Deleting all firewall rules

        foreach (INetFwRule2 rule in fwPolicy2.Rules)
        {
            fwPolicy2.Rules.Remove(rule.Name);
        }

        // Adding rules from the List to the windows firewall 

        INetFwRule2 newRule;

        for (int i=0; i < RuleList.Count; i++)
        {
            newRule = RuleList[i];

            try
            {
               fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);
            }
            catch (Exception r)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error adding rule firewall");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, it throws on `fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);`, right?

Comment: Yes, and the requested execution level of the program is the highest available if that matters.

Comment: I would have to test this but could it be that it fails because you're addimng back on instance of a rule that you just removed? I would expect you would do a Activator.Create("HNetCfg.FWRule"); and then populate the properties on that new instance you got from the old list. Then add that fresh instance to the Rules collection.

Comment: Thank you very much man but could you be a little more specific by giving me some example code?